# Roles in postgres not inheritet by user

Tags: postgresql

I have create 2  roles .
Read only and full_access  like this.

```
CREATE ROLE read_only;
CREATE ROLE full_access;
```

the i add with grant privileges

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES  ON DATABASE db_test TO read_only;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_test TO full_access;
```

after that i create a user

```
CREATE USER ex;
ALTER USER "ex" WITH  PASSWORD '00000' ;
grant full_access TO "ex" ;
```

The user ex has the role but it cannot perform  select read update on all tables. what is wrong?
I want the user ex to be in the role full_access and be able to read write update tables. BUT only from a role because i have to add also other users to this role.
I have to add other users to the role read_only and only read.

I do not want to add to user select read write update  but to get(inherit form full_access role) it from the role .
Other user will get the read only access from the read_only role .

- Here some photos

[the role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbQk1.png)  [role permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uUE4.png) [user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KZ3C.png) [user properties permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCYQE.png)
Is it possible ?
thanks

```
    CREATE ROLE test_schema_read_only;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test TO test_schema_read_only;
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA test TO test_schema_read_only;
    GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA test TO test_schema_read_only;
    REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM test_schema_read_only;
     

    CREATE ROLE test_schema_full_access;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test TO test_schema_full_access;
    GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA test TO test_schema_full_access;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA  test TO test_schema_full_access;
    GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA test  TO test_schema_full_access;
    REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM test_schema_full_access;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA test GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO test_schema_full_access;
    
    
    
    DROP USER IF EXISTS "ex";
    CREATE USER "ex";
    ALTER USER "ex" WITH  PASSWORD '00000' ;
    GRANT test_schema_full_access TO 'ex' ;
    
    
    DROP USER IF EXISTS "sec";
    CREATE USER "sec";
    ALTER USER "sec" WITH  PASSWORD '00000' ;
    GRANT test_schema_read_only TO 'sec' ;
```

Also hier the result of \ztable and \du user
[result of \z and \du](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsc3x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your first `GRANT` is a syntax error. But your whole approach is flawed: granting permissions on the database won't give you any permissions on tables in the database.

Use a combination of

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA x TO read_only;
```

and

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA x TO read_only;
```

to achieve your goal. You'll have to run that for each schema.

Comment: I  have try all these but it's not working. I get query executed no errors but although the user is in the role  has no permissions on the tables like the role.

Comment: Can't be. Perhaps you can add some proof to the question.

Comment: i posted some pics

Comment: You misunderstand; I guess I wasn't clear enough. Edited pictures from a GUI I don't know tell me nothing. What is needed is a reproducer: A series of SQL statements that I can run on my machine to get the same behavior that you see.

Comment: just changed the  post with the commands. The first commands i have try with no affect

Comment: Thanks. That looks fine, except that you grant `CREATE` on the schema to the read-only user. After these commands, the role and all its members will be able to `SELECT` from the tables in that schema. Note that that only holds for tables that existed when you granted the permissions. It does *not* apply to tables created later.

Comment: Yes but the user has no readwrite access for full access and no read access for only read access . I dont know what is wrong . Although is added to the role .

Comment: Can you show the result of `\z table_name` and `\du user_name` in `psql` for the table and the user?

Comment: Already did. The pics that i have post are from the db Beaver the resut is the  result of the commands but in a GUI.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that output anywhere in your question. Anyway, maybe somebody else can understand your images and give an answer.

Comment: I add a pic of psql .

Comment: Thanks. That user can definitely `SELECT` from that table, unless the user was created with `NOINHERIT`. If that's not the case, then it must be a trivial mistake, like you are connecting to a different database or connecting with a different user.